# Java- Eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am fairly new java and programming as a whole. Currently i follow a guide to java programming but a few of the programs don't execute accordingly in eclipse mars but execute without problems on ideone.com. An example:

```
class Vehicle{
    int  Passengers, mpg, Fuelcap, Size;
    boolean running,  full, Fueltankempty;

    void range(){
        System.out.println("Range is " + Fuelcap*mpg);
    }
}

class AddMeth{
    public static void main (String args[]){

        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle sportscar =new Vehicle();

        minivan.Passengers=7;
        minivan.Fuelcap=16;
        minivan.mpg=21;

        sportscar.Passengers=2;
        sportscar.Fuelcap=14;
        sportscar.mpg=12;


        System.out.println("minivan can carry "+minivan.Passengers+" with a range of " );
        minivan.range();
        System.out.println("sportscar can carry "+sportscar.Passengers+" with a range of ");
        sportscar.range();
    }
}
```

When executing I get the following error message:

```
minivan can carry 7 with a range of 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Vehicle.range()V
    at AddMeth.main(AddMeth.java:26)
```

Does anybody know why I get the message?

Comment: There is no problem at all.

Comment: The code is running with no issues.

Comment: Looks like method exists in classpath during compilation, but not during running of your application.

Comment: I don't use eclipse for a while. But have you tried to recompile you classes? It looks like the code that you pasted here is not the code that you are running on your machine. Btw, you should read also about java best practices and code conventions. (cammelCase, getters/setters (arguable), fields and methos visibility... )

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile your code, each time you made a change to your source code and want to run your program. If you are usingan IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, it will (by default) automatically build/recompile.

In Eclipse, check, whether you have activated `build automatically`, which is in the `Project` menu.

Comment: ...which is under the `Project` menu.

Comment: I have the build automatically option activated. I disabled and re enabled it but still no change.

Comment: Try `Project > Clean ...` and use the option to `Start a build immediately`?